# How to call action that is in a different controlle in play framework?

Tags: playframework

I have a controller Foo in play framework scala project:

```
In Foo controller (in Foo.scala) I have action 
object Foo extends Controller { 
def baz() = { 
 Application.bar() 
}
```

In baz action I want to call bar action defined in controller 
Application (in controllers.scala) . But above does not work as I get 
compile error Application.bar does not take parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
Action(Application.bar)
```